# why cant i connect through odbc in visual studio c# to mysql server?

Tags: c#, mysql, odbc

why cant i connect through odbc in visual studio c# to mysql server?

Here is the visual studio's connection to the database:

```
System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection conn = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection();

conn.ConnectionString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2 ANSI Driver};Dns=data;  

Server=localhost;Database=test;User=root;Password=******;Option=3;";

conn.Open();
```

And here is the odbc configuration:

[image]

Here is the error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Comment: why don't you use another method to connect are you familiar with `using System.Data.SqlClient;` checkout this link here it will show you how to connect / setup different connection strings
[C# ConnectionString](http://www,connectionstrings.com)

Comment: Isn't that for Mssql only, MethodMan?

Comment: Use MySQL connector  (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection) , http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/ , http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-connecting-open.html

Comment: Check the fourth example,  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-connecting-open.html